# How to change my caps lock key to work as a tab?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

My tab key has never worked and I want to switch it's function with the caps lock key since I never use caps lock anyways. I'm using OSX and they only way I've seen to change the function of the keys has been through Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys. But there's no tab option. Can anyone help me? I also tried using KeyRemap but it didn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There’s no tool called KeyRemap, but there is Karabiner Elements.  Have you tried that?  There’s also a way to do this via the command line (see the dupe link).  Also, what version of macOS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org). It's a free, open-source app that lets you remap keyboard keys. It's completely safe to use.